# How can I configure my .htaccess file in my website filemanager in ipage.com?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I was chatting to operators with ipage.com for help I tried to create my own `.htaccess` file and uploaded it then they tried to create `.htaccess` file and configure it almost for two days and no solution.

The problem is that the `.htaccess` file is in my root directory but it doesn't work with all sub directories and if it does then I can't surf to my regular main website.

The first time the fixed the `.htaccess` file to work with my new html file I created and uploaded to my site:

[Testing html file](http://newsxpressmedia.com/testingphp.html)

The content of this file is:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Use PHP in HTML files</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <h1>
        <?php echo "It works!"; ?>
        </h1>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I'm trying to use php code inside html file.
Now this is not working but if they change something in the `.htaccess` file this `testingphp.html` will work I will see "It works!" but then if I will surf/browse to my regular main site:

[Main site page](http://newsxpressmedia.com/)

Then I will get this error :

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time
>   the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have
>   caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

And they change it back I can surf to my website but then the `testingphp.html` won't work it will not show "It works!" when I will browse to it.
The problem is that each time only one of the pages is working.

What I want to do is to make `.htaccess` file in my root directory in my filemanager that will work with all existing html files and subdirectories and all future html files I will create in the future and upload to the filemanager.

The qustion is:

Why the `.htaccess` file is not working ?
The `.htaccess` file is not visibe in my filemanager at ipage.com so this is the content of the `.htaccess` file maybe someone here can see the bug or know how to fix the problem?

```
# Begin cache control #
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresActive off
<FilesMatch ".*">
Header unset Cache-Control
Header unset Expires
Header unset Last-Modified
FileETag None
Header unset Pragma
</FilesMatch>
# End cache control #
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.html index.shtml index.xhtml index.wml index.perl index.pl index.plx index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.js index.jp index.php4 index.php3 index.php index.phtml index.htm home.htm default.htm index.fcgi


#Weebly Additions Start
DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.xhtml index.wml index.perl index.pl index.plx index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.js index.jp index.php4 index.php3 index.php index.phtml index.htm home.htm default.htm index.fcgi
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php

Options -Indexes
# Send send no-cache headers for root (/) and (.html) files
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(^/|\.html)$" HTML_FILE
Header add Pragma "no-cache" env=HTML_FILE
Header add Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate" env=HTML_FILE
Header add Expires "-1" env=HTML_FILE




RewriteEngine On


# stop condition
RewriteRule ^mobile/.*$ - [L]

#Redirect urls based on a query string parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?view=mobile([^&]*)&?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?m%1%3 [CO=is_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},CO=disable_mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST},L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m*(.*&)?view=full([^&]*)&?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%3 [CO=disable_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},L,R]

# only process HTML files
# ----------------------------------------------------

RewriteRule (^|\.html)$ - [S=1]
        # is an html file, start the tests...

RewriteRule .* - [S=9]
        # NOT html file, skip past mobile rules...


# tests
# ----------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mobile$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?m [CO=is_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},CO=disable_mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST},L,R]
        # set cookies, redirect...

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^full$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [CO=disable_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},L,R]
        # set cookies, redirect...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;)\s*is_mobile=0
RewriteRule .* - [S=6]
        # skip past mobile rules...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;)\s*disable_mobile=1
RewriteRule .* - [S=5]
        # skip past mobile rules...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;)\s*is_mobile=1
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]
        # go to mobile rules...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [CO=is_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},S=1]
        # go to mobile rules...

RewriteRule .* - [CO=is_mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST},S=2]
        # set cookie, skip past mobile rules...


# mobile rules
# ----------------------------------------------------

RewriteRule ^$ /mobile/index.html [S=1,PT]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/$1 [PT]
#Weebly Additions End
```

In the `.htaccess` file there are lines with weebly inside I used to edit my site using weebly.com but now I don't use weebly.com anymore I'm using ipage.com filemanager where my site is hosting at ipage.com

The reason is that I read that weebly not supporting php and ipage.com does support.
So maybe there is way to change the `.htaccess` file to not working with weebly but only with the hoster ipage.com ?

In my filemanager there is also a file name called: `.htacces.config` but this file is empty.

Also I see a file called `.htaccess.swp` but I can't edit it and can't see it's content.

And last there is also a file called: `.htaccess.txt` and it's content is:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Maybe someone here can find the problem why the `.htaccess` is not working with all html files all subdirectories and all html files I'm uploading or creating new ones ?

The only file I created was `.htaccess.txt` and I uploaded the file and also `.htaccess.config` which is empty.

The `.htaccess` file called: `.htaccess` this one was/created by ipage.com operators/helpers.
But so far nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's because `Wordpress` can't create the `.htaccess` file in `Filemanager`.

I had the same issue but the thing worked for me was:

1. Go to root in `Filemanager`
2. Create a new file named `.htaccess` having extension `.htaccess`.
3. Now go to `WordPress Admin Panel` and move to `settings/permalinks` now click `save changes` button.

It will generate `code` for you in the recently created `file`.

If `Wordpress` Fails to do so than you it will show some `code` at the end of page

Just `copy` the code and `paste` it in the file manually.